# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when user unfollows project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app users can follow projects. I've been following Michael Hartl's guide on following users and adapting it along on the way for following projects.

I've currently got follow working but when I click unfollow I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

about the following part in my Follows controller:

```
def get_followed_project    
  @project = Project.find(params[:follow][:followed_id])
end
```

The rest of the destroy action is:

```
def destroy
  current_user.unfollow_project!(@project)
  redirect_to @project
end
```

The form partials for following and unfollowing are:

```
<%= form_for current_user.follows.build(:followed_id => @project.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "button" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for current_user.follows.find_by_followed_id(@project), :html => { :method => :delete } do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

These methods are in my User model:

```
def follow_project!(project)
  follows.create!(:followed_id => project.id)
end

def unfollow_project!(project)
  follows.find_by_followed_id(project).destroy
end
```

I have this in my routes.rb:

```
resources :follows, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

and this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

I've found if I bypass the before_action for destroy and instead put this at the start of the action:

```
@project = Follow.find(params[:id]).followed_id
```

it works, but then this fails:

```
redirect_to @project
```

I'm not entirely sure why that line works but I'd rather get it working as per the guide, any ideas?

Comment: I'd bet `params[:follow]` is empty

Comment: also `follows.find_by_followed_id(project).destroy` what is the local variable `follows` come from  ??

Comment: Yea I think so too but I'm not sure why or what is supposed to go into it. I believe that takes @project from the form which gets it from the page the form partial is called from - the show view

Comment: When you click "Unfollow", this form hasn't a field named "followed_id", so `params[:follow][:followed_id]` will throw an error, add `f.hidden_field :followed_id` and try again?

Comment: yes see there is a lot of errors on his code

Comment: Ok that seems to be working but now it is redirecting me strangely to the edit_user_registration path from Devise.

Also, why was this hidden field not required in Hartl's tutorial? Is it due to his being for user to user following rather than users following another model?

Comment: Correction, it redirects to the author of the project's profile, so project.user even though my controller specifies project as the redirect_to

Comment: Ok, my bad, was a User. in my controller instead of Project.

Everything is fixed now, thanks :)

@Bigxiang, would you put your comment as an answer to I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click "Unfollow", this form hasn't a field named "followed_id" and your form hasn't any inputs, so `params[:follow][:followed_id]` will throw an error, add `f.hidden_field :followed_id` to your form:

```
<%= form_for current_user.follows.find_by_followed_id(@project), :html => { :method => :delete } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```